# Magento2 Exception "No such entity with cartId = " on checkout when the customer is logged out

Tags: magento2, checkout

I'm developing a custom theme for Magento2 based on Luma.

So, when I open the checkout page without a customer logged I receive this exception.

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): No such entity with cartId = 
...
```

Based on other similar problems I found on the web, I tried running this sql:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `store_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

but without success.

I understand that the cartId is empty, but I don't know how fix this.

Comment: Have you ever find solution on this?

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: Have you found any solution for that? we have same issue coming it